# Deployed SFML Game not finding resources?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, installation, windows-installer, sfml

I am using SFML 2.0 and Visual Studio 2010 professional to create a game. When I test my game from within Visual Studio, it works perfectly fine, loads up all the resources. It has no problem finding all of the resources.  However, when I build my setup.exe file and install my game, the deployed version cannot find the resources.

I feel like this has to do with where it is looking for the resources within Visual Studio compared to when it is installed on the system. Within Visual Studio, the program accesses a "res" folder that is in the default directory with the project file. Shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dkq7.png).

When I install the game, I package the "res" folder to be installed next to the .exe [like-so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaS3g.png).

However, when I run the deployed game, it cannot find any of the resources, and thus, crashes. I feel like this is a real simple fix, just a matter of me placing the "res" folder in a different location, but I have been messing with it for a while and cannot get this to work. Where do I place the "res" folder in the installer?

Answer (score 1):

Given you have not provided any code, I'll assume you're loading your resources with relative paths. This means that your application will be looking for the files relative to the working directory. Now the working directory can be changed and Visual Studio does so and sets it to where the project file is located in (by default). When you now run your application by double clicking on it, the working directory is where you application itself is located. As such your setup should work.

However if you have a conjunction or you start the application from within your setup, you need to make sure the working directory is set correctly.

Additionally you could also change the working directory within your application, but this will require some platform specific code (or the use of for example Boost's Filesystem).